# How to run commands on HDInsight cluster from the code?

Tags: python, azure, putty, azure-hdinsight

### Problem description

I have an instance of **HDInsight cluster** with which I'm connecting using **Putty and CAPI Certificate**. Once I'm trying to connect it asks me for a **special PIN number**(assigned to a card which needs to be plugged in during connection) which I need to enter manually and then I'm able to login, execute commands etc. But the problem is that I would like to have a possibility to **run commands on HDInsight cluster** from the code **from my local machine**.

### Question

Is there a library for Python which enables me to do it from the code?
Basically I would like to execute following scenario(written in pseudocode):

1. login to HDInsight cluster
2. execute i.e. "ls /path/to/directory"
3. see the output of a command above in the console on my local machine

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimum working example I put together where I can SSH into my cluster via python, and run some simple unix and beeline commands. I used Python 2.7 but it should work in 3.x too (just put brackets on the print ;))

Let me know if this is what you were looking for!

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

clusterConnection = "sshpass -e ssh <cluster_user>@<cluster_name>-ssh.azurehdinsight.net"

env = os.environ.copy()
env['SSHPASS'] = '<cluster_pass>'

sshProc = subprocess.Popen(clusterConnection.split(), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env=env)
time.sleep(3)

sshProc.stdin.write("ls /\n")
sshProc.stdin.write("echo 'Hello!'\n")
sshProc.stdin.write("beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001/;transportMode=http' -e 'show tables' > test.txt\n")
sshProc.stdin.write("cat test.txt\n")
sshProc.stdin.close()

for line in sshProc.stdout:
    print line
```